# Cannot access web page with credentials from java

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, ioexception

I'm accessing RabbitMQ Queue information from java code.

```
    public class NewClass {
    private static Object Base64Converter;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            try {

                String credentials = "test" + ":" + "test";
                String encoding = base64Encode(credentials);
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.30:15672/api/queues");
                URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
                uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String inputLine; 

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // Process each line.
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close(); 

        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            System.out.println(me); 

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }
  private static String base64Encode(String stringToEncode)
  {
    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(stringToEncode.getBytes());
  }
```

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://192.168.0.30:15672/api/queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prepare a URLConnection with proper authentication but then you don't use it when you call `url.openStream()`. This should work:

```
 ...
 URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
 uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));
 uc.connect();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
```